# How to test for increase of multiple time series?

Tags: regression, time-series, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression

Every year there is a special test given to a group of people. Therefore my data set consists of the results of this test, one per subject per year. I have the data for 5 years: something like:

```
subject|year1|year2|year3|year4|year5
```

The hypothesis is that there would be an increase in results as the years pass.

I'm not sure how to solve this. If I take just one subject, then I can do a linear regression t-test (assuming linearity) and test whether the slope is greater than zero. But how can I collect these results together?

I thought of two possibilities:

1. Calculate the slope for each subject, then somehow test the whether this new data list has more positive values than would otherwise be. I feel that this method ignores the individual strengths of the slopes.
2. Somehow build a multiple regression model: where there are many dimensions (through use of dummy variables) such that each dimension only really considers the data of one subject.

Could either of this ideas work, or is there something else that can be done?